# Can I Install sharepoint foundation 2013 in my machine with 4GB RAM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

My System is Core2 duo with 4GB RAM & 320GB Hard Disk,

Can i install SharePoint Foundation 2013 in system, currently i am using windows 8?

Please tell me those who are using, I am confuse about RAM, I haven't try till now but I want to make sure before install is it possible or not with 4GB RAM for install.

Answer (score 2):

this is simply bad choice to install sharepoint foundation along with database on a machine with 4GB ram and Core2Duo processor. May be you able to install it but running the SharePoint on this hardware will be a night mare.

MSFT recommend minimum 8GB ram & 4 core x64bit processor for the development / evaluation machine.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx#hwLocServers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#hwLocServers)

Comment: To add, at least with 2010, you could not/should not install it on a machine at was not running windows server (08,12). 2013 has the advantage of allowing remote development where you install visual studio on your machine and develop against a server.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 officially supported installing on Windows 7 (as a development environment), however 2013 is not supported on a Windows 8 OS, even for development.

SharePoint is designed to be installed on a Server environment, not a desktop OS (they have different features installed and configured).

If you intend to do SharePoint development, I suggest you create a VM (Windows 8 includes Hyper-V server, or you could use Virtualbox) and run SP2013.

That said, 4 GB RAM you will struggle for a dev VM. MS recommends much more RAM, and the Search and Distributed Cache services will not run on that amount of RAM.

One option you have is to use Windows Azure VMs - they have VM templates with SharePoint 2013 installed for devleopment purposes.

Another option is to use Office 365 (SharePoint Online), which is hosted in the "cloud," so you don't have to worry about configuring SharePoint, you can just use it.